# Click on all elements with a certain ID

Tags: javascript, html

I've been creating a program that I created an easter egg for. I want the easter egg to be that it will infinitely click on elements with the ID a. I've written a script to do this, but it clicks on only one of those elements and then stops. For reference, when an element is clicked on it generates another element.

```
function click(){
       document.getElementById("a").click()
      }

      if(hxor){
          setInterval(click, 20)
      }
```

Thanks!

Comment: id values must be unique in a given page; two attributes with the same id is a mistake.

Comment: @Pointy can you show me how to recursively give elements id (example: para.id = "a" + myVar; myVar++)

Comment: @Squill.is.me don't give them IDs like that. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same ID for multiple elements in a single page.
One way you could approach this is give each element a unique ID, and record those IDs in an array. Then just loop through the array and click each element individually.
Without more information I can't offer more than that.

Comment: Now, how would I recursively create elements with different ID's?

Comment: How many do you have? Using a class like Mark said in his comment is probably a better option.

Comment: Infinitely many. When one element is clicked on, it generates another.

Comment: If you can't use a class, you could just have a counter that increases by 1 each time you create a new element. After you create a new element, just do 
element.id = counter

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all elements, you could use classes

```
<input type="text" class="myclass">
<input type="text" class="myclass">
<input type="text" class="myclass">

function click(){       
   elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")
   return elements
  }
```

Comment: I've been trying to implement this code using JS to click on all of these elements. Do you mind checking my repo to see if there's an error (willmargulies.com/cris.htm)

Comment: @TimGraupner  ^^^

Comment: It will return elements that has class "myclass", if you want to generate make an event when clicked you can verify if(elements.length > 0)  then throw event.

Comment: This function doesn't produce a click on the element. Do you know why?                function click(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")
if(elements.length === 0){alert("oi")}
elements.click();
      }